# Posting image on Facebook wall it is too small and not saved in photos album in android java

Tags: java, android

This is my code to post image on my facebook wall its done successfully.   `but image is not saved in photos on facebook album and it is too small.`

```
     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("picture", imageurl); // imageurl ="http://bks6.books.google.ca/books?id=5VTBuvfZDyoC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&+zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api" 
     b.putString("caption","This is deme");
     b.putString("description","Download " );
     b.putString("name","Demo Name");
     b.putString("message","Download  www.google.com \n  Vote For tp://abc.com");
     b.putString("link","WWW.google.com");  // demo link
     String strRet = fb.request("/me/feed",b,"POST");
```

`My image should look like this` but its not happening. i mean in `big size`.see bellow image. .

[image]

see the image which i `posted on wall its too small and its not saved in album.`
[image]

please help me ..

Comment: You can also replace my code to fetch from URL by searching on google with search string "fetch image from url to byte android".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following parameter.

```
b.putString("method", "photos.upload");
//..other extras
```

replace following line

```
fb.request("/me/feed",b,"POST");
```

with

```
fb.request(null, b, "POST");
```

Following is full code.

```
FileInputStream fis;
try {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(imageUrl);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    int imageLength = (int)(entity.getContentLength());
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        baos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    data = baos.toByteArray();

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);
    params.putString("caption",
            "your Caption\nYour Caption");

    String resp = facebook.request(null, params, "POST");
}
```

Comment: hey i am getting the error when i have added these tow lines  ``

Comment: Error: Requires upload file

Comment: Okay..got it.. my fault. What i did is, i have byte[] of image and i am passing it to upload to FB. My code will only allow if it has **data** in **byte[]**. If you want, i can post full code.

Comment: Hey Chintan can u send me the code for convert image in byte array from URL.. plz

Comment: yes. It is what i did. May alternate solution there. I have posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be uploading images to someone's album rather than to their wall (as you're doing).

Try this: (I realize this example is php, and not java... I'll see if I can dig up the java sample).
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

edit:
Here's an Android sample:
http://sunnysharma4android.blogspot.com/

Comment: Hi friend .. but i don't know about PHP. could u send me in android /java

Comment: I did, it's the second link.